# LDAP search yielded 0 matches when trying to authenticate using devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.1, I used devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable for authentication with ldap. I followed all the steps which mentioned in the below link
https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable. when I am trying to login I got the following error
ldap.yml :-

development:
  host: zeus.corp.ads.valuelabs.net
  port: 389
  attribute: samaccountname
  base: DC=corp,DC=###,DC=####,DC=net
  ssl: false

LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: cn=ykakarla
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: cn=ykakarla
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
  LDAP: Authorizing user cn=ykakarla,DC=corp,DC=###,DC=####,DC=net
  LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.

I found the issue and I changed my ldap.yml

development:
  host: zeus.corp.ads.valuelabs.net
  port: 389
  attribute: cn
  base: OU=USERS,OU=MOBILE TEAM,OU=PROJECTS,OU=#####, DC=corp,DC=####,DC=#####,DC=net
  ssl: false

now when I am giving my cn i.e yaswanth kakarla, it's getting authenticated.
it is searching only top directory.but I need to search subtree also.

Any help.

Thanks